# I want to trasfer a image from one android mobile to another both are connected to wifi lan?

Tags: android, network-programming

there are two android devices which are connected to wireless lan i.e WiFi. I have to send the picture from one device to another, where ip addresses are known. I want to use UDP or TCP

Comment: Cool go ahead...  oh  What is the question? I suggestion to read the FAQ to know how to ask a question ( this way you'll have better answer)

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the Sockets for the transfer. There will be client sending the image and the server will receive that image..
Follow this:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/

[Socket Programming -Java - Many Clients One Socket Question(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719802/socket-programming-java-many-clients-one-socket-questions)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/85736a40d7f95dd8